# How to PING Google by using service account to check if connection does work

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

What is the best way to use Google Service Account to check if connection established so can continue to execute the code?

Looking forward to some handle which will check the connection before executing the code:

E.G.

- If the connection established  - then continue
- If the connection established but no permission - then continue
- If the connection DO NOT establish - throw an exception

Comment: Can you explain about the detail of `check if connection does work`? I cannot understand about `connection` in your question.

Comment: @Tanaike What I have currently done is  - created a function which tries to query test table from BigQuery, then try to copy file from google storage... and e.t.c... Need something which will ping GCP services and check that everything is fine

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about `something which will ping GCP services and check that everything is fine`. I apologize for my poor understanding.

Answer (score 0):

As Google APIs are exposed using HTTP, what you usually do is check the [return codes](https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/) of the HTTP calls to make sure that everything is ok.

According to this, the google-api-python-client is smart enough and it tries to make your life easier. If everything is ok (status code 2XX) it will automatically load the data in a python dictionary, otherwise (status code 4xx or 5xx) the library will raise an exception that you can catch to act accordingly.

The best practice is to perform requests using an [Exponential Backoff logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff). This approach is also [recommended by Google](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#best-practices) in the official Big Query documentation. Usually, my library of choice to manage exponential backoff in python is [tenacity](https://github.com/jd/tenacity).

Answer (score 0):

Send a request to one of the basic endpoints using the access token you have, such as:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=<access_token>
```

or

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=<access_token>
```

If you get a `200` response, then your connection is successful.